# How to change the layout of a product page

Tags: plugin-wp-e-commerce, genesis-theme-framework

I'm using WP-ECommerce with the genesis framework.  I can set the layout of the Products page to single column, but when I select a single product it uses the default layout and not the products layout.  I'm not sure where to even begin.  Is this a configuration issue with WP-EC or with the genesis framework.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, all I needed to do was add the following to the function.php of my genesis child-theme.

```
add_action('init' , 'wpec_genesis_add_layout_support');

function wpec_genesis_add_layout_support(){
add_post_type_support( 'wpsc-product', 'genesis-layouts' );
}
```